# How to call php (stored on a server) using vba/vbs

Tags: php, vba, cmd, vbscript, putty

I want to call php using vba or vbs. The php file is stored on a server.

I am able to do it if the php file is stored locally:

```vb
Sub asasdsad
    Call Shell("C:\xampp\php\php.exe C:\path\file.php", 1)
End Sub
```

This calls the php which executes a code for me. My problem is, the .php file I want to call is stored on a server, for which I've got username and password of course. Copying file to local directory is not an option as it's got a lot of includes.

My idea is to use PuTTY to connect to the server, and use it to execute above command, all from cmd using vba/vbs.

```vb
UserName = "un"
Passwrd = "pw"
'this would need additional parameters at the end to call php.exe like above
Call Shell("""C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\putty.exe"" " & "-ssh " & UserName & "@ip address -pw " & Passwrd, 1)
```

As you can imagine there will be a lot of parameters so it just get complicated, not ever sure if this would work. I've never used PuTTY and all of this is quite new to me. I'm sure there's a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do not use PuTTY, use [Plink (PuTTY connection tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html). It's a console application designed for automation (contrary to PuTTY, what is GUI application, designed for an interactive use).

Plink (again contrary to PuTTY) can accept a command to be executed on its command-line (it has a similar command-line syntax as [OpenSSH `ssh`](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh)):

```
"C:\...\plink.exe" -ssh username@ip_address -pw password /path/to/php /path/to/script.php
```

Comment: Fantastic, it works! :) Thank you Martin, never thought of calling php scripts from excel or vbscript... daamn, it opens a whole new world!